# Existence of sets

Tags: set-theory

Just wondering how you could prove whether or not the follow sets exist.

For each of the following predicates $\phi (x)$ prove whether the following sets exist {x : $\phi (x)$}

1: $\forall y(y\in x)$

2: $\forall y(x\in y)$

3: $\exists y(y\in x)$

4: $\exists y(x\in y)$

I have that 3 and 4 dont exist as they imply the existance of the set of all sets. Not sure about 1 and 2 i think they exist but are empty.

Comment: How can $ x $ be quantified in (2) and (4), if it's the argument of $ \phi(x) $?

Comment: my bad, copied the question wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. is the set of all all-sets. Since that no all-set exists (i.e., the class of all sets is proper), $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ is the empty set.
2. *(after the question was edited)* is the empty set because $x\in y$ cannot hold for all $y$ when it does not even hold for $y=\emptyset$ (nor for $y=x$)
3. is the class of all non-empty sets, which is a proper class as it would have to have itself as element if it were a set.
4. is the class of all sets (and so not a set) because we can always pick $y=\{x\}$.

Comment: If 3 {x : $\phi$ x} is the set of all non empty sets then, cant you construct A = $\forall y(y\in x)$ U {the empty set} which is the set of all sets. So 3 cant exist

Comment: @kam007 That's why I said "would be". At any rate, this set itself *would* be non-empty, hence have itself as element - not good